# Change height of a class with JQuery for each element "foreach"

Tags: jquery, foreach, height, each

I have a foreach that retrieve the information from processwire.
In each row there are an image (class = Img1) on the left and a description inside a div (class = Test2) on the right.
I want to measure the height of both the image and the div containing the description, choose the biggest and set it to the height of the div containing the image (class = Test1).
The problem with the actual code is that at the first iteration, the largest height is stored and applied to all the rows and not just the first one.

I know I am supposed to use the each() iterative function, I was trying to understand how it works but I was unsuccessful.
Could someone help me please?

HTML

```
    <?php $Ser = $pages->get("name=services");?>
<section id="<?=$Ser->title;?>" class="mea-service-section section-padding-shorter">
  <?php $i = 0;
      foreach($Ser->ServicesRepeater as $Ser):
      $image = $Ser->ServicesRepeaterImage2;

      $colFirst = "";
      // if ($i%3 == 0) $colFirst = 'col_first'; //
      $i++; ?>
      <div class="container">

    <div class="row mt-10" style="display: flex;">


    <!-- Services Widget Section -->
    <div class='outer-row' id="<?=$Ser->ServicesRepeaterHeadline;?>">
      <div class="col-md-5 mea-title-section wow animated slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".2s">
      <div class="media-left-center vertical-align Test1">
        <img src="<?=$image->url;?>" alt="<?=$image->description;?>" class="Img1 img-responsive center-block rcorners3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 <?=$colFirst;?> single-service-widget wow animated fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
      <div class="Test2">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="subtitle"><?=$Ser->ServicesRepeaterHeadline ?></h2>
          <p><?=$Ser->ServicesRepeaterDescription ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</section>
```

JQuery

```
var divImgHeight = function() {
  var divHeight = $('.Test2').height();
  var imgHeight = $('.Img1').height();
  if (imgHeight < divHeight) {
    $('.Test1').css('height', divHeight+'px');
  } else {
    $('.Test1').css('height', imgHeight+'px');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  function resizeLinks(){
    divImgHeight();
  }
  $(window).on("resize", resizeLinks);
  resizeLinks();

    });
```

The actual page under construction: https://brightnode.io/en/services/

Comment: _"the largest height is stored and applied"_ - No, it's not the _"largest"_. It's the height of the first matched element with class `Test2` (or `Img1`) -> `.height()`: _"Get the current computed height for the **first element in the set** of matched elements"_

Comment: As you've only got one "row" in your sample HTML, it's a little hard to determine where `.Test1`, `.Test2` and `.Img1` apply in relation to each other (especially combined with the inconsistent indenting)

Comment: I have added the entire section in the HTML code. You can see the foreach now. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the outer div is one "row", give the outer div a class so it can be referenced:

```
<div class='outer-row' id="<?=$Ser->ServicesRepeaterHeadline;?>">
  <div class="col-md-5 mea-title-section wow animated slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".2s">
    <div class="media-left-center vertical-align Test1">
      <img src="<?=$image->url;?>" alt="<?=$image->description;?>" class="Img1 img-responsive center-block rcorners3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 <?=$colFirst;?> single-service-widget wow animated fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
    <div class="Test2">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="subtitle"><?=$Ser->ServicesRepeaterHeadline ?></h2>
        <p><?=$Ser->ServicesRepeaterDescription ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then loop through `.outer-row` and apply your code to each row, using `this` to reference the row, eg:

```
$(".outer-row").each(function() { 

  // at this point "this" is each of the .outer-row divs in turn

  var divHeight = $('.Test2', this).height();
  // or
  var imgHeight = $(this).find('.Img1').height();
```

giving:

```
var divImgHeight = function() {
  $(".outer-row").each(function() { 
    var row = $(this);  
    var divHeight = $('.Test2', row).height();
    var imgHeight = $('.Img1', row).height();
    if (imgHeight < divHeight) {
      $('.Test1', row).css('height', divHeight+'px');
    } else {
      $('.Test1', row).css('height', imgHeight+'px');
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  function resizeLinks() {
    divImgHeight();
  }
  $(window).on("resize", resizeLinks);
  resizeLinks();
});
```

---

**EDIT**

To apply the largest height across all of them, you'd first need to loop through the items to get the largest height, then loop through each row to apply.  You can apply some shortcuts but the concept is the same.

```
var divImgHeight = function() {
  // get all the heights from .Test2/.Img1
  var heights = $(".outer-row .Test2,.outer-row .Img1").map(function() { return $(this).height(); }).toArray();
  // get the largest height
  var maxheight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);

  // apply to all .Test1s
  $(".outer-row .Test1").css('height', maxHeight+'px');
}
```

Comment: Now it works, thank you!
What if I wanted to look to the largest div of all the rows and apply that height to all the orws?